# how to loop over the elementary arithmetic symbols

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, elementary-functions

I want to check if 7 digits can get to 100 when putting elementary arithmetic symbols between them.

```
def is_hundred(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7):
    p = [+,-,*,/]
    for p1 in p:
        for p2 in p:
            for p3 in p:
                for p4 in p:
                    for p5 in p:
                        for p6 in p:
                            if n1 p1 n2 p2 n3 p3 n4 p4 n5 p5 n6 p6 n7 == 100:
                                return "success"
```

how can i replace the variables with the arithmetic symbols that are in the list?

Comment: you are better off deconstructing the loop

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: each operator has its own circuit, so trying to find a 'generalised circuit' is probably impossible. instead use 'if (p1='+') plus(n1,n2); if (p1='*') times(n1,n2)', etc...

Comment: that is simple for two digits but i want to do it for 7

Comment: your pseudo-code doesn't work for 7 as it stands anyway

Comment: you could replace p with an array of functions: p=[plus,minus,times,divide]

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't hear it: using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is evil. So that's definitely *not* code that I'd put in production. That said, this exercise is also something that I will probably never have to deploy to prod...

The idea: use the arguments and "brute-force" all the possibilities of adding operations between them. Construct these options as strings, and for each one of them, when done, evaluate the total (using `eval`) and if the total is 100 - print it to stdout:

```
def is_hundred(args, res=''):
    if res == '':
        res = args[0]
        args = args[1:]
    if not args:
        if eval(res) == 100:
            print(res)
    else:
        first = args[0]
        for op in ['+','-','*','/']:
            is_hundred(args[1:], "{}{}{}".format(res, op, first))


# you can pass any number of arguments in a list: 7, 8, 15...
is_hundred([2,3,4,8,10,11])  # 2+3+4+8*10+11
```

Comment: can you explain what is eval, args, and what is .format ?

Comment: added a link to `eval` in the answer, args - is the list of numbers that you're passing to the function and `format` is a string-method, in the example above: `"{}{}{}".format(res, op, first)` is equivalent to: `res + op + str(first)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code which search a pair of operators. the `i` in `iadd` means inplace `add` operator. You can simply switch to `add`. `product` creates duplicate permutation of operators.

```
from operator import iadd, isub, imul, itruediv
from itertools import product

operators = (iadd, isub, imul, itruediv)

def is_hundred(values):
    n_operators = len(values) - 1

    for ops in product(operators, repeat=n_operators):
        value = values[0]
        for op, v in zip(ops, values[1:]):
            value = op(value, v)
        if value == 100:
            print(list(ops))
            return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_hundred([99,1,1,1,1,1]))
print(is_hundred([1,1,1,1]))
```